Which alternating groups are characteristic 2 type?
First, let's recall the definition of characteristic 2 type (I think this is correct, but I am not 100% sure). For any 2-local subgroup $H$ of $G$, if $H$ contains the entire Sylow 2-subgroup, all elements of $H$ that centralize the 2-core $O_2(H)$ are in the core itself; in other words, the quotient group acts faithfully on the core by conjugation.
From what I've seen, the alternating groups up through $A_{10}$, except $A_7$ are characteristic 2 type. Under the alternate notion of "even type" (used in the second-generation classification), $A_{12}$ is added; in particular, $A_{12}$ is not a group of characteristic 2 type.
The alternating groups up through $A_8$, except $A_7$, are groups of Lie type in characteristic 2 (or the derived subgroup, in the case of $A_6$), so it seems fairly straightforward that these groups are characteristic 2 type. I can also see why $A_7$ and $A_{12}$ are not characteristic 2 type: they have 2-local subgroups that do not satisfy the above definition, $(A_4\times3):2$ and $(A_4\times A_8):2$, respectively (in both cases, the core is an elementary Abelian group of order 4 and have centralizers $2^2\times3$ and $2^2\times A_8$, respectively).
When I first thought about this, it seems that by the same logic, $A_9$ and $A_{10}$ should not be characteristic 2 type either. When I looked a bit more closely, I realized that the subgroups $(A_4\times A_5):2$ and $(A_4\times A_6):2$ do not contain the entire Sylow 2-subgroups. A11 would have the same problem, but we can use a different 2-local subgroup by partitioning 11 points into 3, 4, and 4. This group is $((A_4\times A_4):2^2\times3):2$. Indeed, it contains the entire Sylow 2-subgroup, and the core is an elementary Abelian group of order 16, which is centralized by a 3-cycle outside the core.
The case I am confused about is alternating groups $A_n$ for $n=2^k$ points. Here, any 2-local subgroup obtained from a partition does not contain the entire Sylow 2-subgroup. Unless I am missing something, the only 2-local subgroups containing the entire Sylow 2-subgroup are those obtained from wreathed duads or tetrads, which are $2^{\frac{n}{2}-1}:S_\frac{n}{2}$ and $A_4^\frac{n}{4}:(S_\frac{n}{4}\times2^{\frac{n}{4}-1})$, respectively. The cores of these subgroups are elementary Abelian of order $\frac{n}{2}$ and $n$, respectively, and they are self-centralizing. By this logic, any alternating group on $2^k$ points should be characteristic 2 type, as should the alternating groups on $2^k+1$ or $2^k+2$ points (using the same argument that I gave for $A_9$ and $A_{10}$).
So my conjecture is, an alternating group $A_n$ is of characteristic 2 type if and only if $n$, $n-1$, or $n-2$ is a power of 2. Is this correct?

Please use MathJax. Here is a
tutorial.

Thanks, I didn't know how to embed LaTeX, but it should be good now.
